# Extract hashtags from a string in Excel

Tags: excel

How can I extract multiple hashtags from a string in Excel? I played around with MID and SEARCH formulas but couldn't come up with anything good.

```
**Example input:**
Daniel Craig primed for action on SKYFALL (2012) and SPECTRE (2015). #007 #JamesBond #DanielCraig

**Example output:**
#007
#JamesBond
#DanielCraig
```

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: Read [ask] to improve your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 2013+ with the `FILTERXML` function you can:

- convert the string into an XML, using the spaces for the different nodes

  - `"<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A$1," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>"`
- use an `Xpath` to extract the nodes containing the `#`

  - `"//s[contains(.,'#')]`
- in the formula,  `[" & ROWS($1:1) & "]")` becomes a **position** argument in the xpath so it will sequentially return the first, second, ...nth node that matches the condition.
- The `IFERROR` is to blank out the result if you fill down more than there are hashtags.

---

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A$1," ","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'#')][" & ROWS($1:1) & "]"),"")
```

In the example, I placed the formula in `A3` and filled down five rows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, here are two examples showing mid() with find().

Expand as you wish, you may want to check out iferror()

I suggest you take them apart to see and understand what is happening.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing this, but I needed to add an excel add-on. (credit and instructions to add go to this website http://blog.malcolmp.com/2010/regular-expressions-excel-add-in  ) If you add this add-on, then the formula you'd need is =xMATCHALL("#[\S]+",A1,FALSE)

[image is from excel, showing this in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvbZJ.png)

I've added some variables into your example to show that it picks just the words immediately following the hash tag