# Searching cell for specific phrase (XYZ), locating Left nearest phrase (ABC) find values after ABC and totals

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column of cells with long strings of text. In these cells are sometimes a repeating phrase, say "XYZ". I need a formula to find all instances of "XYZ" in the cell, then look to the left of "XYZ" and find the phrase "ABC" each time and after "ABC" there is a value (#). I need to then SUM all these values.

So, I need to add the values that immediately follow "ABC" when "ABC" appears prior to "XYZ" for each time that appears.

There will absolutely be other instances of "ABC" NOT associated with "XYZ" so I need that pairing.

The number of times "XYZ" appears is not static, nor is it's placement in the cell.

Thank you for any help you all can provide. Any questions to clarify please let me know.

The cell being searched has a string of text similar to the below as an example:

ABC: 1 | lorem ipsum | lorem ipsum | lorem ipsum | lorem ipsum | ABC: 1 | lorem ipsum | ilorem ipsum | XYZ | ABC: 1 | lorem ipsum | lorem ipsum | lorem ipsum | ABC: 8 | lorem ipsum | lorem ipsum | ABC: 1 | lorem ipsum | XYZ

In this instance it would be a value of 2, but that can vary in the value that follows ABC. There is not a limit to the number of times XYZ may appear, and the same for the ABC that precedes it. The value itself is also not a constant in number of characters, it could be single digit or triple digit or so on

Comment: would you be open to a solution using **Power Query** which is availelbe in Excel 2010 and later versions? Let me know and I will show you a walk through solution.

Comment: Many q&a about this, have a search on here.  This is but one : https://stackoverflow.com/q/57288099/4961700